# How to correctly import custom source generation packages

Tags: flutter, dart, sourcegenerators

I am trying to use a source generation package that I have written myself called `animated_widget_generator`. the annotations package is called `animated_widget_annotations` and the app I am trying to use it for is called `example_usage`.

I added the necessary packages to my `dev_dependencies`. here is my `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
name: example_usage
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  animated_widget_generator:
    path: ../animated_widget_generator
  animated_widget_annotations:
    path: ../animated_widget_annotations
  build_runner: ^2.0.4

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

but when I try to run the app on my phone, it gives me the following errors:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A6003 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/flutter (17052): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(242)] Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime
E/flutter (17052): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(169)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter (17052): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(401)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (17052): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(571)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
Exited (1)
```

there are other questions on Stack Overflow about this error but they are always about some third party package and not about a custom source generation package and it doesn't seem like any of the answers to those questions are relevant to me

EDIT: `pubspec.yaml` for `animated_widget_generator` and `animated_widget_annotations`:

```yaml
name: animated_widget_annotations
description: A new Flutter package project.
version: 0.0.1
author:
homepage:

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
```

```yaml
name: animated_widget_generator
description: A new Flutter package project.
version: 0.0.1
author:
homepage:

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.17.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path: ^1.8.0
  source_gen: ^1.0.2
  json_serializable: ^4.1.3
  animated_widget_annotations:
    path: ../animated_widget_annotations

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  pedantic: ^1.11.0
  build_runner: ^2.0.4

flutter:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because the package `dart:mirrors` package is not available with flutter.

Do check these conversations on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-dev/c/ZmX5gZHhU24) and [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150) for more info.

An alternative package called [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) is available for reflection, however it has limitations at this time.

Comment: I did not import the package ```dart:mirrors``` to my app! how can I make flutter avoid including the package with my app so it does not produce this error?

Comment: Well if you've not directly imported you've already done your job, maybe along the way in one of the other packages `animated_widget_generator` or `animated_widget_annotations` its been imported?

Comment: my understanding is that these packages are only a dev dependency and should therefore be able to import what ever they want.

Comment: That's right. But its hard to say why its not working without seeing the code for the generators.

Comment: I added pubspec.yaml for the generator as well. does that help clarify the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. If have a repository (github/gitlab) that you're willing to share with me, I think we can find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233790/discussion-between-eyal-kutz-and-rohan-thacker).

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common problem with upcoming flutter developers. The main reason is that the flutter and dart are getting updated quickly. Sometimes after their upgradation let's say after this latest version of Flutter 2.2, you can see on their github that some packages are removed from their stable mode in order to work on them to make them more efficient. So, you can't access those packages. Make sure that you either find an alternate package for the same task or try to change the version number of the dependency to a lower number which might work because of backward compatibility. pubspec.yaml can be very difficult to understand if you have version problem because it will tell you that the dependency doesn't exist but won't tell you the reason.

Comment: lt seems that all packages I use are up to date and compatible with the latest version of flutter so I do not think that is the issue